# Using MicrosoftReportViewer with Web Forms programmatically

Tags: asp.net

I'm repeating my question because the prior one under this topic was lost.
Could you please help me? I want to use MicrosoftReportViewer for Web Forms so that the DataSource be set programmatically. There is some sample code on the Internet for Windows Forms but I haven't found anything for Web Forms. For example, here is some code I've tried to use. It gives no errors but nothing is displayed.

How should I modify the code to display a table in the ReportViewer?

Imports System.Data
Imports Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms

Partial Class TestReportViewer
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    CreateReport()
End Sub

Sub CreateReport()
    Dim dt As DataTable
    Dim rpt As ReportDataSource
    dt = New DataTable("Sample")
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("No", GetType(Integer))
        .Columns.Add("Name")
        .Rows.Add(1, "A1")
        .Rows.Add(2, "A2")
        .Rows.Add(3, "A3")
        .Rows.Add(4, "A4")
        .AcceptChanges()
    End With
    rpt = New ReportDataSource
    rpt.DataMember = "Sample"
    rpt.Value = dt
    rpt.Name = "test"

    With ReportViewer1
        .LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rpt)
        .DataBind()
        .LocalReport.Refresh()
    End With
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link:
http://odetocode.com/articles/128.aspx

You can basically do the same as in WinForms:

Instantiate ReportViewer in your code behind and set

```
 ReportViewer reportViewer1 = new ReportViewer(); 
 reportViewer1.ServerUrl="http://localhost/ReportServer";
 reportViewer1.ReportPath="/SampleReports/Sales Order Detail";
```

Or

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("datasetname", dataSet.Tables[0]));
```

Michael